# How can I debug a GWT application while it's running on Tomcat

Tags: maven, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea, gwt

I am new to GWT but have been a Java developer for a few years. I have just been added to a team in charge of a Web Application that uses GWT and can't figure out how to debug the Java code either in my browser or within my IDE. I have searched high and low for an answer and after a week of failing to debug, I'm here.

Here's my setup:

- IDE: IntelliJ Ultimate Edition
- Maven for dependency management
- Git for version control
- Tomcat for the web server

The web app has multiple maven modules, I can expand on that if I need to.

When I run the application to test new code, I do a mvn clean, mvn install, and then run a small script that starts the web app on Tomcat.

Script: 
mvn -N -Dcargo.run -Dcargo.debug -Dcargo.debug.suspend=n

The script contains other variables appended on the end but I've omitted them due to their sensitivity.

How do I run this web app in development mode so that I can debug the Java code either in my browser or in IntelliJ? Can I run my script and then start the debugging process or does the debugging process have to start first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to run and debug gwt it is to launch `mvn gwt:run-codeserver`

Then navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:9876`

Grab the bookmarklet, drag it in your browser bookmark bar.

Go to the gwt application page running in tomcat `http://localhost:8080/gwtpage.html`, click the bookmarklet and magic should happen.

Comment: Thank you, though my configuration was a little more advanced, this did ultimately help!